# Reading Input Line by Line

Tags: c++, file-io, getline

Currently i can read a file with just one line, but i need to reas several lines and place each line into a seperate string.

```
ifstream file("test.txt");
ostringstream ss;
cout << "File" << file.get << endl;
ss << file.rdbuf();
cout << ss.str() << endl;
const string& s = ss.str();
```

This piece of code just reads one line and pastes it in string s.

Comment: Shouldn't `file.get` be `file.get()`? Please post **actual** code.

Comment: That code should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::ifstream stream("file.txt");
std::string line;
std::vector<std::string> lines; 
while (std::getline(stream, line)) {
    lines.push_back(line);
}
```